# Error in Python regarding Attributes missing (formatted the right way hopefully)

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror

I'm trying to define a method called getX on my object as it's 2nd of 3 parts to a problem (It's part of a longer problem as I'm doing a stand-alone online course so no help)

Here's what my class looks like

```
class V2:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return 'V2[%s,%s]' % (self.a, self.b)

    def FindThis(self, a, b):
        self.getX = self.a
        self.getY = self.b
```

I then type

```
v = V2(1,2)
v.getX()
```

When I create an instance of this class and call .getX() I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
v.getX() AttributeError: V2 instance has no attribute 'getX'
```

note: The goal of this program is to define basic part of the class with an init and str methods so that if you do

```
print V2(1.1,2.2)
```

it prints

```
V2[1.1,2.2]
```

and then write two accessor methods (`getX` and `getY`) that return the x and y components of the vector

My struggle-point is not knowing how to use/where to put getX and getY in my program to deliver what the problem is asking me to do

Note: I've posted the question before but in a terrible format and didn't make clear what I needed help with. Hope this was clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a few adjustments to your code:

```
class V2:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.x = a
        self.y = b

    def __str__(self):
        return 'V2[%s,%s]' % (self.x, self.y)

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def getY(self):
        return self.y

v = V2(1,2)
>>> print v.getX()
1

>>> print v
V2[1,2]
```

Comment: question: when writing the line `return 'V2[%s,%s]' %(self.x,self.y)` could you remove the "self." before x and y?

Comment: @tsh39, No you can't.